# Click em Botão usando o Selenium Basic com VBA

Tags: vba, login, selenium-webdriver, button, automatização

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa de dados automatizada em uma pagina do meu trabalho, e não consigo passar da parte de login, consigo inserir o Login e Senha, mas todas as tentativas de acessar o botão "Entrar" são em vão.
Estou iniciando nesse mundo, então me desculpe pelo código.

Basicamente a pagina de entrada possui apenas os elementos: Login, senha e o botão entrar.

Segue o código fonte da pagina:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>nome</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;FF=3;OtherUA=4" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div id="header-line" class="header-line"></div>
<div style="width:100%;background-color:#0064ae;">
    <div style="width:100%" class="blue-gradient-background">
        <div  class="header-content">
            <table style="width:98%">
                <tr height="40px">
                    <td style="width:30%"><a href=""><img src="images/logo_x.png" alt="x" style="border: 0" /></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 40%"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 30%;color:white;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%" class="silver-gradient-background">
    <div class="content">
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr height="30px">
                <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
        <div id="content" class="content">
            <form method="post" action="/x/login" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

                <div class="form-content">
                    <center>

                        <h2>
                            <label class="header-title">Bem-Vindo ao x</label>
                        </h2>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Login:<td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="matricula" style="margin-left: 4px; font-size: 11px;" /><td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Senha:<td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="senha" style="margin-left: 4px; font-size: 11px;" /><td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div style="width:500px;"><label style="color: red;width:100%;vertical-align: super; padding-left: 20px;"></label></div>
                        <div style="width:500px;"><button style="font-size: 11px;" type="submit">Entrar</button></div>
                    </center>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>


        <div class="login-footer">

            <div class="silver-gradient-background">
                <table id="formFooter:j_idt43"
                    class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget no-border"
                    style="height: 35px !important; width: 100% !important; white-space: nowrap !important;"
                    role="grid">
                    <tbody>
                        <td style="text-align: center; width: 20%"><label
                            class="subtitle">© </label></td>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu código basicamente, abre o IE(tem que ser por ele) e pesquisa os dados que preciso, mas, pra isso tenho que estar com a pagina já aberta.
Gostaria de fazer algo mais eficiente e abrir a pagina e logar.

Segue a parte do código:

```
internet.Navigate "site que quero entrar"
internet.Visible = True

While internet.Busy Or internet.ReadyState <> 4
DoEvents
Wend
internet.Document.all("matricula").innerText = MyLogin
internet.Document.all("senha").innerText = MyPass >até aqui tudo certo
internet.Document.TurbonetOss.acao.Value = "Entrar"
internet.Document.TurbonetOss.submit
```

Answer (score -1):

Ola
Tente este codigo

```
internet.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click
```